# How to check, where an user clicked into the DIV?

Tags: jquery, events, live

I am thinking about the situation, how to know, where an user clicked to DIV.

```
<div class="abc">
  <a href="#" class="def">xxx</a>
</div>

$("div.abc").live('click', function(e) {
  alert('message');
})
```

If I will use this part of code, so if I will click somewhere into the **DIV.ABC**, so I will get the alert message **message**. This is okay.
But I need this message only in the moment, when a user'll click to the place into **DIV.ABC**, **NOT ON THE A ELEMENT, THAT IS IN THE DIV.ABC**. Is possible to do it?

Thanks in advance ;)

**EDIT:**
Sorry guys, I apologize to you. Of course, everywhere in my script are the letters lower. My Problem is, how to ignore **alert('message')**, when I will click on the anchor in div.abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$("div.abc").live('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'a')  
  alert('message');
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/RJHDy/

Answer (score 3):

`e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()` will give you the type of element that was the original source of the event.  In your case, you can check that it gives you `div` instead of `a`.

Comment: While this works for this specific situation, I seriously don't recommend doing it this way as this gets very brittle very fast. What if I've got a `DIV` inside a `DIV` I want to avoid, for example? I'd have to argue that it's best to leverage the event model in this case. :D

Answer (score 0):

The `stopPropogation()` method stops events from bubbling up the tree. But beware, it also stops other event handlers attached to those elements from executing, if they're meant to execute after this one.

```
$("div.abc").live('click', function(e) {
  alert('message');
})
$("div.abc>*").live('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropogation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you refer to the jquery selecting your div abc it is somehow focusing on the anchor tag because of the "a" section. Try rename your div and reflect it into your jquery. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `live` method in your example, so could just do something like this below.

```
$("div.abc").click(function(e) { alert('message'); } ).children().click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropogation();
   alert('message');
});
```

e.stopPropogation will stop any events from bubbling up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.stopPropagation()`.

```
$('div.abc').click('live', function() {
    // this does what you want
    alert('message');
});

$('div.abc *').click('live', function(e) {
    // but we don't want that to happen
    // when we click on anything else inside
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```